# Stability of the ipython api

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, pymc3

working with pymc3 in ipython4 I get some errors that concern the api of ipython:

```
ShimWarning: The `IPython.html` package has been deprecated. You should 
import from `notebook` instead. `IPython.html.widgets` has moved to
`ipywidgets`. "`IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`.", ShimWarning)
./lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets 
has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package."
```

Is this part of the api sufficiently stable that I is worth to try to stabilize the code on it or is it still under heavy development ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with IPython's API. There is a pull request awaiting merge that eliminates this warning.